# MapboxGL.js Advanced Error

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

I am creating a webmap using MapboxGL.js and just updated from 0.21.0 to 0.24.0 for the scale bar functionality. I am using custom vector tiles that I generated using Mapbox studio and rendering information client side with geojson. However, after updating to the most recent release I am now getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'advance' of undefined

Working around a bit I found that unmodified Mapbox templates such as the Outdoor theme do not cause this error when I publish them from my Mapbox Studio Account but both customized tilesets that I use from Studio throw the same error.

Any thoughts of what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a bug in GL JS. Could you post this question on the [GL JS issue tracker](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/new)? Please follow all the instructions in the issue template. Thank you!